# pdflscape counterclockwise landscape with section

Tags: header-footer, rotating, landscape, pdflscape

New on Latex world, using `pdflscape` package, I'm trying to create a counterclockwise landscape page (header on left and footer on right).
This page has a `\section` for its title.

I've managed to create a new environment `counterlandscape` using `etoolbox` package and `\patchcmd`.

But the result is not what I've expected. The section is on the bottom right of the page instead of the upper left.

Using `graphicx` or `rotate` package, I did not managed to change it.

Here is a sample :
https://www.overleaf.com/read/ctzpwwzprtsk#b3977b

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{pdflscape}

% Make landscape counter clockwise (header on left, footer on right)
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\let\counterlandscape=\landscape
\let\endcounterlandscape=\endlandscape
\patchcmd{\counterlandscape}{\PLS@Rotate{90}}{\PLS@Rotate{-90}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{counterlandscape}
    \section{Titre 1}
\end{counterlandscape}

\end{document}
```

I do not know if my approach is the good one or if there is a better one.

Do you know how to achieve this? My goal is to have a landscape page with header on left and footer on right with section on the upper left.

Any help would be appreciate.

Thanks

Mikk

Comment: How do you want things to look when viewed electronically vs. when printed? Because `pdflscape` pulls those two things apart.

Comment: Hello @cfr,

Thanks for your response.

If i use landscape, header is on the right of the page and footer on  the left. Section well diplayed on the upper left of the page.
Because i have a large picture to display on page, which i can not change its orientation and some text is wrongly oriented, i simply want to flip landscape to display header on left and footer on the right.

This document should not be printed but idealy, if it is, it would be great if it looks as electronical display.

Hope i'm clear :)

Comment: `landscape` rotates the content of the page but not the header or footer. If you use `pdflscape`, the page is additionally rotated in the viewer, if this is supported. This does not affect how the page is printed. `landscape` with `lscape` rotates the text body anticlockwise 90 degrees. `pdflscape` rotates the resulting page clockwise through 90 degrees. That's all `pdflscape` adds to what `lscape` does. It doesn't touch what is on the page. It just tells the pdf viewer to turn it through 90. Since the text body is turned -90 and the page is rotated 90, the text body is orientated for reading.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to mostly be a matter of thinking more carefully about what is being rotated by what.

We need to define not `counterclockwiselandscape` (or, even, `anticlockwiselandscape`) but `clockwiselandscape`. As a result, we want the PDF viewer to rotate the page *anticlockwise* rather than clockwise, as it typically does. I tried to figure out how to do this with `pdflscape` but gave up. It's a whole lot simpler to use `lscape`'s `pdftex` option and patch a copy of its `landscape` environment, without the complications of `pdflscape`.

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{lscape}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentEnvironment{clockwiselandscape} {}
{%
  \def\LS@rot{\setbox\@outputbox\vbox{\hbox{\rotatebox{-90}{\box\@outputbox}}}}%
```

`lscape` defines this outside the `landscape` environment, but we redefine it here so regular `landscape` environments are not affected. For reasons I don't understand some things rotate in one direction and some in another. `-90` actually rotates *clockwise* in this case, whereas the default `90` rotates anticlockwise.

```
  \@clockwiselandscape
}{%
  \end@clockwiselandscape
}
\let\@clockwiselandscape\landscape
```

`\@clockwiselandscape` is a simple copy of `\landscape` and does not require patching.

```
\let\end@clockwiselandscape\endlandscape
\patchcmd \end@clockwiselandscape {\pdfpageattr{/Rotate 90}}{\pdfpageattr{/Rotate -90}}{\typeout{Patched clockwise landscape.}}{\typeout{Failed to patch clockwise landscape!}}
```

This patch means the PDF viewer will be instructed to rotate the page anticlockwise rather than clockwise. Here, `-90` rotates anticlockwise, whereas the original `90` rotated clockwise.

```
\makeatother
```

We can then use the `clockwiselandscape` environment for our content.

```
\begin{clockwiselandscape}
  \section{Title}
  \includegraphics{example-image}
\end{clockwiselandscape}
```

[image: clockwiselandscape with anticlockwise rotation in viewer]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
% ateb https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/700004/ i gwestiwn Mikk: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/699688/
\usepackage[pdftex]{lscape}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentEnvironment{clockwiselandscape} {}
{%
  \def\LS@rot{\setbox\@outputbox\vbox{\hbox{\rotatebox{-90}{\box\@outputbox}}}}%
  \@clockwiselandscape
}{%
  \end@clockwiselandscape
}
\let\@clockwiselandscape\landscape
\let\end@clockwiselandscape\endlandscape
\patchcmd \end@clockwiselandscape {\pdfpageattr{/Rotate 90}}{\pdfpageattr{/Rotate -90}}{\typeout{Patched clockwise landscape.}}{\typeout{Failed to patch clockwise landscape!}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
No rotation.

\begin{clockwiselandscape}
  \section{Title}
  \includegraphics{example-image}
\end{clockwiselandscape}

This shouldn't be rotated.
\end{document}
```

The surrounding pages are to ensure the effect is properly contained by the environment.

[image: portrait, clockwiselandscape and portrait pages]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @cfr for your great and complete response. And for your spent time on my problem.

I tried to use your solution (using lscape package with pdftex option) that seems the better solution but unfortunatly, this package do not work with my templates. I've spent some time to understand why but did not found and gave up.

I've finaly found a solution (not the prettiest but it works).
I now patch both lscape and pdflscape commands :

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% Invert lscape rotation
\patchcmd{\LS@rot}{90}{-90}{}{}
% Make landscape counter clockwise (header on left, footer on right)
\patchcmd{\landscape}{\PLS@Rotate{90}}{\PLS@Rotate{-90}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

This made my 'fancy' footer too high in the page so i had to change my geometry to make it fixed :

```
\geometry{
    ...
    top=1.2in,
    bottom=1in
    ...
}
```

For now, this solution fit to my needs but i'd like to understand why lscape package with pdftex option do not work with my template. Maybe some updates soon...

Again, thank you very much.

Mikk